# Linear transformation of a normed linear space to another normed linear space..

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Suppose a linear transformation $\Lambda$ of a normed linear space $X$ into a normed linear space $Y$.
Im trying to prove that,,,..
If $\Lambda$ is continuous at one point of $X$ then $
\Lambda$ is bounded.

Proof: 
Suppose $\Lambda$ is continuous at $x_0$. To each $\epsilon>0$ there exist $\delta>0$ so that $\lVert x-x_0 \rVert<\delta$ implies  $\lVert \Lambda x-\Lambda x_0 \rVert<\epsilon$. In other words, $\lVert x \rVert<\delta$ implies $\lVert\Lambda (x+x_0)-\Lambda x_0\rVert<\epsilon$. But then the linearity of the transformation $\Lambda$ shows that  $\lVert\Lambda x\rVert<\epsilon$.
Hence, $\lVert\Lambda\rVert\leq \epsilon/\delta$. This completes the proof.

I don t know how the last part of the proof was obtained.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see this is looking at the definition using vectors of norm 1. For all $0<t<1$, we have that $$\|\Lambda\|=\text{sup}\{\|\Lambda x\|: x\in X, \|x\|=1\}=\text{sup}\{\|\Lambda\frac{x}{t\delta}\|:x\in X,\|x\|=t\delta\}=\text{sup}\{\frac{1}{t\delta}\|\Lambda x\|:x\in X,\|x\|=t\delta\}=\frac{1}{t\delta}\text{sup}\{\|\Lambda x\|:x\in X,\|x\|=t\delta\}<\frac{\epsilon}{t\delta}.$$

Note that this is enough to show that $\Lambda$ is bounded. To get the result at the end of the above proof, we may take a limit as $t\to 1^-$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \neq 0$ then $y=(1-\frac 1 n) \delta \frac x { \|x\|}$  is a vector whose  norm is $(1-\frac 1 n) \delta <\delta$. Hence $\|\Lambda y\|<\epsilon$. By linearity this gives $\|\Lambda x\|<\frac {\epsilon} {1-\frac 1 n} \frac 1 {\delta}\|x\|$. $\,\,\,$ (1)Let $n \to \infty$. [ $x=\|x\| (1-\frac 1 n)^{-1} \delta ^{-1} y$ so $\Lambda (x)=\|x\| (1-\frac 1 n)^{-1} \delta ^{-1} \Lambda ( y)$. Since $|\Lambda  (y)|<\epsilon$ we get (1)].

Comment: Are you saying that the norm of y is $(1-\frac{1}{n})\delta$? How?

Comment: Just use the fact that $\|ax\|=a\|x\|$ for all $a$. Take $a= (1-\frac 1 n) \frac  {\delta} {\|x\|}$.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Lastly, By linearity this gives $\|\Lambda x\|<\frac {\epsilon} {1-\frac 1 n} \frac 1 {\delta}\|x\|$. I dont how we arrive to this

Comment: @Heisenberg Just write $x=cy$ for with $c>0$ by solving the equation defining $y$ for $x$. Then use linearity.

Comment: Its hard, i cant imagine

Comment: Its confusing...

Comment: I dont know how you obtain the last inequality

Comment: @Heisenberg I have added more details to my proof.

Comment: So that if we tend n to infity then $\|\Lambda x\|<\frac {\epsilon} {\delta} \lVert x\rVert$.. Right?

Comment: And since $\|\Lambda x\|\leq\|\Lambda\|\|x\|$ then we have the deiared conclusion right?

Comment: Right. So $\|\Lambda\| \leq \frac {\epsilon} {\delta}$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Thank you for teaching me.